# replace Regex with $replaceAll mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to replace all the unnecessary text in the field

For example I have this:

```
_id:12345678901,
name:"Company Z"

_id:12345678902,
name: "Corp Y"

_id:12345678902,
name: "Corporation X"
```

And I want to remove `Corp`, `Corporation` and `Company` in the field `name`, and make a new field for it, but I can't do it with regex

Target:

```
_id:12345678901,
name: "Company Z",
newName: "Z"

_id:12345678902,
name: "Corp Y",
newName: "Y"

_id:12345678902,
name: "Corporation X",
newName: "X"
```

Currently I have this:

```
db.customers.updateMany(
  {  },
  [{
    $set: { newName: {
      $replaceAll: { input: "$name", find: {"$regexFind": { input: "$name", regex: '/(Corp)|(Corporation)|(Company)/gi' } }, replacement: "" }
    }}
  }]
)
```

But it doesn't seems to work.

BTW im using mongod 4.4.14

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `$regexFind` doesn't return a string, but an object [doc](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/regexFind/)
First you have to do `$regexFind`, and after use the returned objects match field to to the `$replaceAll`. Here is an example aggregation pipeline which transforms your objects to the desired ones:

```
  {
    $addFields: {
      "regexResObject": {
        "$regexFind": {
          "input": "$name",
          "regex": "(Company )|(Corporation )|(Corp )"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      regexResObject: {
        $ne: null
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      newName: {
        $replaceAll: {
          input: "$name",
          find: "regexResObject.match",
          replacement: ""
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      regexResObject: 0
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: it's kinda works, but some how, if `name` isn't contain the regex, `newName` is returning null. Any suggestion?

Comment: yes, thats why I filtered them out. you could write a [conditional](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) to add the original field if the value is null.

Comment: I don't believe you can use $match inside of $updateMany.  So if you do this approach, you'll have to (bulk) write them all back.  May be simpler to just do it in code, depending on database size and how many matches you think you'll get.

Answer (score 1):

Building off of aaronlukacs answer, but fixing for the fact that you can't use `match` inside an update pipeline:

```
db.customers.updateMany(
  {  },
  [
    {
      $addFields: {
        regexResObject: {
          $regexFindAll: {
            input: '$name',
            regex: '(Company )|(Corporation )|(Corp )'
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      $addFields: {
        newName: {
          $reduce: {
            input: '$regexResObject',
            initialValue: '$name',
            in: {
              $replaceAll: {
                input: '$$value',
                find: '$$this.match',
                replacement: ''
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      $project: {
        regexResObject: 0
      }
    }
  ]
)
```

Note that if there are no matches, newName should just be name.  I also used regexFindAll, which will eliminate more than one instance of the regex match... not relevant here but might be for other cases.